# Why can I not see my texture using QOpenGLWIdget, it only shows a black box?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

So I am fairly new to using QOpenGLWidget (Qt 6.6) I am passing in a QImage to my custom QOpenGLWidget and when I show the widget, it only display a black box. I have had a look around and can not find any solutions. Any suggestions?

My setup is, I am using a QWidget in Qt Designer as the parent for my custom QOpenGLWidget.

```
#include "OpenGLWidget.h"

OpenGLWidget::OpenGLWidget(QWidget* parent) : QOpenGLWidget(parent) 
{
    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    setFixedSize(500, 500);
}

OpenGLWidget::~OpenGLWidget()
{
    makeCurrent();
    delete m_texture;
    doneCurrent();
}

void OpenGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    // Enable texture mapping
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // Create an OpenGL texture object
    m_texture = new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
    m_texture->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Nearest);
    m_texture->setMagnificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Nearest);
    m_texture->setWrapMode(QOpenGLTexture::ClampToEdge);
    m_texture->create();
    if (m_texture != nullptr && m_texture->isCreated())
    {
        // Create and compile shaders
        shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex,
            "#version 330\n"
            "in vec2 vertexPosition;"
            "in vec2 vertexTexCoord;"
            "out vec2 texCoord;"
            "void main() {"
            "    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition, 0.0, 1.0);"
            "    texCoord = vertexTexCoord;"
            "}");

        shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment,
            "#version 330\n"
            "in vec2 texCoord;"
            "uniform sampler2D textureSampler;"
            "out vec4 fragColor;"
            "void main() {"
            "    fragColor = texture(textureSampler, texCoord);"
            "}");

        // Create vertex buffer
        GLfloat vertices[] = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
             1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
             1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        };

        vertexBuffer.create();
        vertexBuffer.bind();
        vertexBuffer.allocate(vertices, sizeof(vertices));

        // Create vertex array object
        vertexArrayObject.create();
        vertexArrayObject.bind();

        shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertexPosition");
        shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertexTexCoord");
        shaderProgram.setAttributeBuffer("vertexPosition", GL_FLOAT, 0, 2, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4);
        shaderProgram.setAttributeBuffer("vertexTexCoord", GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 2, 2, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4);
    }
}

void OpenGLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void OpenGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    // Clear the buffer
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Load image data into the OpenGL texture
    if (!m_image.isNull())
    {
        m_texture->setData(m_image);
    }

    // Use shader program
    if (shaderProgram.bind())
    {
        // Bind texture
        m_texture->bind();

        // Draw quad
        vertexArrayObject.bind();
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
        vertexArrayObject.release();

        // Unbind texture
        m_texture->release();

        // Release shader program
        shaderProgram.release();
    }
}

void OpenGLWidget::setImage(QImage image)
{
    m_image = image;
}
```

I have tried changing the format of the QImage. I have tried passing in the raw data to the texture.

Comment: Apart from anything else you never set the uniform `textureSampler` (as far as I can see).  You should also be checking return values to make sure shaders compile/link successfully etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response @G.M.  . I think I have set it correctly now however, it is still black. The return values were being checked I only removed it to reduce the amount of code displayed here. But all is successful.

Comment: After some investigation there seems to be an issue with my QOpenGLTexture. If I destroy it and then recreate it. I can see the image but its not drawn correctly for example, the image appears upside down, It has also drawn surrounding QWidgets. Over time, the more it redraws itself the more it begins to look like an TV with static lines.

Comment: If you need further help with this please [edit] you question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I copied your example and it works for me in Qt 6.7. Try to download and run it: [black-box-was-fixed.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/7ghll46txtgf03t8kq3gi/black-box-was-fixed.zip?rlkey=mhb7wnkgooarwnj6v0dgqqbxv&dl=1)

[image]

Some notes:

1. Don't call `m_texture->setData(m_image)` every frame inside `paintGL()`. You should call it only once inside `initializeGL()`
2. You should mirror a texture using `QImage::mirrored()`:

```cpp
    m_texture.create();
    m_texture.bind();
    m_texture.setData(QImage(":/assets/textures/box_texture_512x512.png").mirrored());
    m_texture.setMinMagFilters(QOpenGLTexture::Filter::Linear, QOpenGLTexture::Filter::Linear);
    m_texture.setWrapMode(QOpenGLTexture::WrapMode::ClampToEdge);
```

3. Use `QOpenGLShader::ShaderTypeBit::Vertex` instead of `QOpenGLShader::Vertex`, `QOpenGLTexture::WrapMode::ClampToEdge` instead of `QOpenGLTexture::WrapMode::ClampToEdge` and so on (see an example) because that enums was deprecated in Qt 6.

black-box-was-fixed.pro

```
QT       += core gui openglwidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    opengl_widget.cpp

HEADERS += \
    opengl_widget.h

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    assets.qrc
```

assets.qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>assets/textures/box_texture_512x512.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "opengl_widget.h"

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    OpenGLWidget w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

opengl_widget.h

```cpp
#ifndef OPENGL_WIDGET_H
#define OPENGL_WIDGET_H

#include <QtGui/QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QtOpenGL/QOpenGLVertexArrayObject>
#include <QtOpenGL/QOpenGLBuffer>
#include <QtOpenGL/QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QtOpenGL/QOpenGLTexture>
#include <QtOpenGLWidgets/QOpenGLWidget>

class OpenGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, private QOpenGLFunctions
{
public:
    OpenGLWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~OpenGLWidget();

private:
    void initializeGL() override;
    void resizeGL(int w, int h) override;
    void paintGL() override;

private:
    QOpenGLBuffer vertexBuffer;
    QOpenGLVertexArrayObject vertexArrayObject;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram shaderProgram;
    QOpenGLTexture m_texture;
};

#endif // OPENGL_WIDGET_H
```

opengl_widget.cpp

```cpp
#include "opengl_widget.h"

OpenGLWidget::OpenGLWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QOpenGLWidget(parent)
    , m_texture(QOpenGLTexture::Target::Target2D)
{
    setWindowTitle("Example");
    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    setFixedSize(350, 350);
}

OpenGLWidget::~OpenGLWidget() {}

void OpenGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    // Enable texture mapping
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // qDebug() << "OpenGL version:" << (const char*) glGetString(GL_VERSION) << "\n";
    // qDebug() << "GLSL version: " << (const char*) glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << "\n";
    // qDebug() << "Vendor: " << (const char*) glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << "";

    m_texture.create();
    m_texture.bind();
    m_texture.setData(QImage(":/assets/textures/box_texture_512x512.png").mirrored());
    m_texture.setMinMagFilters(QOpenGLTexture::Filter::Linear, QOpenGLTexture::Filter::Linear);
    m_texture.setWrapMode(QOpenGLTexture::WrapMode::ClampToEdge);

    // Create and compile shaders
    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::ShaderTypeBit::Vertex,
        "#version 130\n"
        "in vec2 vertexPosition;"
        "in vec2 vertexTexCoord;"
        "out vec2 texCoord;"
        "void main()"
        "{"
        "    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition, 0.0, 1.0);"
        "    texCoord = vertexTexCoord;"
        "}");

    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::ShaderTypeBit::Fragment,
        "#version 130\n"
        "in vec2 texCoord;"
        "uniform sampler2D textureSampler;"
        "out vec4 fragColor;"
        "void main()"
        "{"
        "    fragColor = texture(textureSampler, texCoord);"
        "}");

    // Create vertex buffer
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    vertexBuffer.create();
    vertexBuffer.bind();
    vertexBuffer.allocate(vertices, sizeof(vertices));

    // Create vertex array object
    vertexArrayObject.create();
    vertexArrayObject.bind();

    vertexBuffer.bind();
    shaderProgram.bind();
    shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertexPosition");
    shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertexTexCoord");
    shaderProgram.setAttributeBuffer("vertexPosition", GL_FLOAT,
                                     0, 2, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4);
    shaderProgram.setAttributeBuffer("vertexTexCoord", GL_FLOAT,
                                     sizeof(GLfloat) * 2, 2, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4);
}

void OpenGLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void OpenGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    // Clear the buffer
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Use shader program
    if (shaderProgram.bind())
    {
        // Bind texture
        m_texture.bind();

        // Draw quad
        vertexArrayObject.bind();
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

        // Unbind texture
        m_texture.release();

        // Release shader program
        shaderProgram.release();
    }
}
```

assets/textures/box_texture_512x512.png

[image]

**Added**

Some changes that allows to run the example above on Android Emulator, Desktop and WebAssembly:

Android Emulator:

[image]

WebAssembly:

[image]

What changes you should make:

1. Shaders must be rewritten to OpenGL ES 2.0 because Android Emulator uses OpenGL ES 2.0. Change `in` to `attribute`, `in/out` to `varying`, and `texture()` to `texture2D()`:

```cpp
    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::ShaderTypeBit::Vertex,
        "attribute vec2 vertexPosition;"
        "attribute vec2 vertexTexCoord;"
        "varying vec2 texCoord;"
        "void main()"
        "{"
        "    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition, 0.0, 1.0);"
        "    texCoord = vertexTexCoord;"
        "}");

    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::ShaderTypeBit::Fragment,
        "#ifdef GL_ES\n"
        "precision mediump float;\n"
        "#endif\n"
        "varying vec2 texCoord;"
        "uniform sampler2D textureSampler;"
        "void main()"
        "{"
        "    gl_FragColor = texture2D(textureSampler, texCoord);"
        "}");
```

2. Delete VAO because OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't have it. Bind VBO in `paintGL()`:

```cpp
    // Use shader program
    if (shaderProgram.bind())
    {
        // Bind texture
        m_texture.bind();

        // Draw quad
        vertexBuffer.bind();
        shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertexPosition");
        shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertexTexCoord");
        shaderProgram.setAttributeBuffer("vertexPosition", GL_FLOAT,
                                         0, 2, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4);
        shaderProgram.setAttributeBuffer("vertexTexCoord", GL_FLOAT,
                                         sizeof(GLfloat) * 2, 2, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

        // Unbind texture
        m_texture.release();

        // Release shader program
        shaderProgram.release();
    }
```

Download: [black-box-was-fixed-android-webassembly.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/7ga5y9o1lvom5747zma7i/black-box-was-fixed-android-webassembly.zip?rlkey=jmksleubbd967b94elcjs0lva&dl=1)

WebAssembly application can be deployed on free hosting like: https://netlify.com/ or https://pages.github.com/ I deployed an example from the topic: https://profound-sunflower-a5633b.netlify.app/ This application can be run from Desktop and Android by one click.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the response but it looks like my issue is a little more complicated from what I've looked at. My input image is a Mono8 image which makes this process incredibly difficult. essentially I get given a ushort* pointer to some data. I know the format is mono8 and I need to convert that to an OpenGlTexture. Trying to do that conversion is not easy. I also have the option of changing the format to mono12 or mono12p.

Comment: I use GIMP to convert from one image format to another. GIMP is a free image editor. You can open an image in GIMP and export it to PNG, for example.

Comment: I added some info to my post above that shows what you need to change in your example to run it on Android Emulator and WebAssembly.